# Space around indices in Mathematica 10

Tags: formatting

When i write something like f(x_0) in traditional form mm puts white space around the index, so that especially the distance to the end parenthesis looks weird. In mm 9 I could reduce the issue by putting a 'negative space' (esc - space space) after the index. But in mm 10 this suddenly looks even weirder with the end parenthesis going through the index. It can be fixed by using af smaller negative space and add a space afterwards as seen on the image below.

My students use both versions, so I wonder if there is a way to make it look the same regardless of which version of mm is used to view a notebook?

This picture shows the problem:
[image]

Comment: Please include pictures of what you are describing.  Words alone are too subjective.

Comment: Also, you can select a text element and "nudge" it by holding Alt and using the cursor keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Kerning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning) in *Mathematica* has longstanding problems in my opinion, though in this case on my system I'm not seeing anything really "wrong."  This looks OK in v10 under Windows:

```
f[Subscript[x, 0]] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

At 18pt font size the kerning is perhaps not ideal:

[image]

However by selecting the right parenthesis and pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> to nudge left I get:

[image]

Unfortunately this manual kerning is the only method of correction I am aware of and it will not port well from one version to another if the kerning changes between versions.